# What is the exact meaning of “You're half a click from your location”?

Tags: meaning

I've got a sentence from the film Black Hawk Down:

(around about 2:04:38 -- 2:04:50)

> -- C-2, this is 64. Where the hell is convey? We're getting fucked here. Over.
>
> -- **You're half a click from your location.** Hang in there.
>
> -- Shit.

My question is: The meaning of the bold sentence is like "You're almost successful."?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an accurate transcription of the scene. Why would the people coming to rescue them say "You're half a click from your location?" That's makes no sense. How can you be any distance from "your location"?

Answer (score 4):

**First part**

A 'klick' is [a military slang term](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/klick) for a kilometer.

So, in the context of the film, this is C-2 replying to 64 that

> You're half a kilometer away from your location.

See also [*Why does “klick” mean kilometer in US military slang?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/85009/109567) on the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

---

**Second part**

By

> Hang in there.

they [mean](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hang-in-there) that they shouldn't give up.

---

So you *could* read

> -- **You're half a click from your location.** Hang in there.

as

> -- *You're half a kilometer from your location. Don't give up.*

But as [Weather Vane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/56820/weather-vane) pointed said in [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/247312/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-youre-half-a-click-from-your-location/247313?noredirect=1#comment464929_247313) below, the reply was "Shit" - implying that they're probably not almost successful.

---

---

There was some doubt about the transcription in the question, so I spent a bit of time looking online. I found a shooting script [here](http://www.mzp-tv.co.uk/movie_scripts/Drama/Black%20Hawk%20Down%20-%20Undated%20-%20Shooting%20script.pdf)<sup>1</sup> which seems to make more sense:

> 254: INT. STEELE'S STABLE COURTYARD - NIGHT
>
> 255: STEELE RADIOS IN
>
> STEELE:
>
> > Six Two, this is Six Four. Where the hell's the convoy? Over.
>
> HARRELL (V.O.)
>
> > Half a block from your location, hang in there.
>
> 256: EXT. EVERSMANN'S POSITION - NIGHT
>
> An RPG slams into the wall, rocking the building.
>
> EVERSMANN:
>
> > Shit!

---

Ignoring the fact that it says "block" instead of "klick", the key thing here is that the exchange is:

> Steele: [...] Where the hell's the convoy? [...]
>
> Harrell: Half a block from your location

instead of

> Steele: [...] Where the hell's the convoy? [...]
>
> Harrell: You're half a click from your location

which means that the *convoy* is near Harrell's location - not that Harrell is near his location (which others have pointed out doesn't make sense).

My reading of the fragment of the transcript is that the convoy is coming to Steele's location (to provide help?).

No matter how I read this I can't see the meaning of the first sentence to be "You're almost successful" - *unless* they convoy is stationary and Steele is moving to the convoy, but that is unlikely because the script says that Steele is radioing from "Steele's stable courtyard".

<sup>1 - I've not seen the film, nor do I have any means to watch it at present. I am assuming that this is accurate - at the very least that the meaning is the same.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure whether this sentence has another meaning that is "You're almost successful." in that context.

Comment: @Darcy it can't mean that in the context, because the reply is "Shit". The person is *nowhere near* the target.

Comment: How can someone be any distance away from their location? Where ever their location is, that's where they are.

Comment: @ColleenV probably from their *target* location, from the location where they are supposed to be. "Your location" – the pickup location you were given.

Comment: More likely it is "We're half a click from your location." Hang in there, we'll be there soon.

Comment: @ColleenV I'm beside myself at your first comment. :-)

Comment: @ColleenV I think "We're" is a better choice too.

Comment: I found a script and have updated the answer.